# How to survive a helicopter crash using alien biotechnology?

Tags: science-based, biology, humans

In the near-future, in a war between aliens and humans, the aliens hatch a plan to seemingly assassinate a human leader (on Earth), but make it look like it was done by other humans. They have it planned for a few months from now, to attack the human when they are traveling (predicted to be by helicopter) to an important summit.

The key word being *"seemingly"*; as revenge for something the human did to piss off the aliens, they want to prevent the human from *actually* dying by using biotechnology to infect the human with something that will make them resistant to the damage from the crash and be controllable by the aliens like a puppet.

***Question:***
What changes does the infection/nanomachine need to do to the human's body in a few months to survive a crash from a height of about 80 - 90 meters (200-ish feet)? The brain at minimum needs to still be intact so that the human can be controllable. If any unimportant body parts get messed up in the crash it's ok, though ideally they should still be able to move around.

***However***, the human cannot have noticeable changes on the outside before the crash (at least not enough to get them sent to the ER to get them checked). They might notice themselves feeling weird or sick or looking a bit different, they just can't be worried enough to go to the doctor in the span of the months before the summit.

**Edit:**

The problem I have is that I want the leader to survive:

- landing on concrete (it's in the middle of a city)
- a rough landing since helicopter rotor is damaged from shrapnel (got partially caught by an explosion of a missile)

And I was having trouble explaining how alien biotech can prevent internal hemorrhaging and brain damage. I would like to know how they can augment the human body to prevent these injuries (in a way that isn't visibly obvious).

Comment: I'm a fan of @Flox's answer, but for future reference, this is brainstorming and per the [help/on-topic], brainstorming is discouraged. Specifically, it's closable as opinion-based because there's no way for us to know how you'll objectively judge a best answer. This is the wrong site to come to if you're experiencing writer's block. It's the right site to come to if you have a specific idea of what you want to achieve (I want the leader to survive the crash by *<insert detailed explanation here>*) but are having trouble working it out (but I'm having trouble with *<this specific issue>*).

Answer (score 8):

My father used to be in the Air Force and spoke many times about the safety features and training required in helicopters.

It may be possible to achieve the Aliens goal by not using nano-tech / biotech at all.

First, there are a myriad of procedures that can mitigate a crash using the safety systems built-in to modern helicopters already. If loss of control occurs at 80m this is a survivable height (this is lower than the normal operating altitude for helicopters). For instance, adjusting tail rotor speed to prevent uncontrolled rotation, and reversing rotor orientation prior to hitting the ground will soften the impact through air cushioning.

It might be more suitable for your aliens to make the crash occur over water. Water crash landings in helicopters are specially trained for in the RAAF. The first thing that occurs in a water landing is the helicopter will 'flip', as the engine is in the top of the aircraft and therefore the heavier component, causing immediate flipping. The training basically concentrates on dealing with disorientation when you are upside down and need to find a way to unclip harnesses, and exit the aircraft, and swim 'up' (not down) as the helicopter sinks.

If your aliens do want to ensure 100% survivability, they should determine if the crash occurs over water, ensure the human is wearing a harness, a vest, a helmet and has undergone helicopter crash / water survival training. If they are still unsure, then perhaps provide the human with the ability to survive longer in water (perhaps increased lung capacity), a stronger spine / neck and skull to prevent blunt trauma and spinal injury, and perhaps an adjustment of adrenaline, dopamine or serotonin levels to ensure calm exit procedures and reduced panic are followed.

Comment: +1 - my first thought was that I don't think they need to modify the human at all - IIRC Blackhawk pilots have survived crashes from that height, with a few broken bones.

Comment: @TheDemonLord is that on water or on land?

Comment: @mer-mech - The one I'm thinking of is the Battle of Moghadishu (AKA Black Hawk Down) when the second Blackhawk fell a distance of 100 ft - The crew survived the initial crash and the Pilot survived the whole ordeal.